# How to optimize simple Postgres query?

Tags: postgresql

I've been analyzing our Postgres queries using pg_stat_statements. There's one query that's in the top 3  that I don't know how to make any better. My goal is to get it executing below 1ms on a regular basis (or as close as I can get it).

Here's the schema

```
create table simple_table
(
    a varchar(5) not null,
    b varchar(120) not null,
    c text
);

create index simple_table_a_index on simple_table (a);
    
create index simple_table_b_index on simple_table (b);
```

After hitting the query a bunch, pg_stat_statements reports this

| userid | dbid | queryid | query | calls | total_time | min_time | max_time | mean_time | stddev_time | rows | shared_blks_hit | shared_blks_read | shared_blks_dirtied | shared_blks_written | local_blks_hit | local_blks_read | local_blks_dirtied | local_blks_written | temp_blks_read | temp_blks_written | blk_read_time | blk_write_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 16401 | 16402 | 1627049242 | SELECT * from simple_table WHERE a = $1 | 2330 | 12577.242999999968 | 2.908 | 101.494 | 5.397958369098713 | 4.503097042744964 | 8157330 | 1106750 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

pg_relation_size for the table is 3760128

The table is ~42000 rows. Generally, this query will return ~3500 rows, with column c being the longest one. Looking at it, the max length is 330, average length is 28.

Any tips on how to improve this very simple query? Beyond adding the index, I'm not sure how to make it better.

Comment: Can you post all the info in [pg_stat_statements](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/pgstatstatements.html) for the query? What is the size of the table? (select pg_relation_size('yourtable'))

Comment: @bobflux Sure, I updated the post with the whole pg_stat_statements row. pg_relation_size for the table is 3760128

Comment: OK, it shows it isn't doing any IO which is good. I've just been experimenting with it and it looks like the time in pg_stat_statements includes time to send results to the client over the network, so your problem might actually be that either the network is slow or saturated, or the client waits too long before retrieving the whole result set.

Comment: Are you using php on the application side?

Comment: It's including transport time? I wasn't expecting that! Ok, cool, I'll look into that. Thanks for the tip.
Edit: the application is written in Java, we're using JDBC 42.2.18.

Comment: I just found out by running the same query that returns lots of rows on local and over network

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is already pretty good.

If you want to squeeze the last bit of performance from the query,

1. Use enough RAM to cache the table and the index on `a` in memory.
2. Rewrite the table in index order:

   ```
   CLUSTER simple_table USING simple_table_a_index;
   ```

Comment: Cool, I'll double check RAM. Also, CLUSTER was new to me, I'll start using it, thanks for the tip!